# Which lattices are ideals of a number field?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, integer-lattices

Let $K$ be a number field, then its ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ in the Minkowski space of $K$ is a lattice $\Lambda$. Is there some geometric descrpition/intuition that describes sublattices of $\Lambda$ of full rank that are ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$?